# Where does the phrase Nitl Nacht come from?

Tags: christianity, evening-night, yiddish

A common Yiddish phrase to refer to the night of the 25th December is Nitl Nacht. Where does this phrase come from and what are the sources for calling it that?

Comment: are you sure that it is not the night of the 24?